# bring pom's profile value on jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles, egovernment

I have dev,local, prod profiles on pom.xml

```
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <env>local</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

is it possible to bring this profile value on jsp? 

 I want to split  some area of jsp with different compile option

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="${isFlag =='loc'}">
            <c:when test="${isFlag =='dev'}">

</>
```